# Typing errors Using const objects

Tags: typescript

I am using const objects as constants throughout my program, but I don't understand this error. On **testA** everything is fine. No type error, but on **testB** I get `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"04" | "01"'.`

In would have thought that hard coded 04 | 01 should be the same as a references to constants.

```
function testA(a:string){
    const ans = ['04','01'].includes(a)
    console.log(ans)
}

function testB(a:string){
    const ans = [cat.green, cat.yellow].includes(a)
    console.log(ans)
}

const cat={
    "yellow": "01",
    "red":"02",
    "green": "04"
} as const
```

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAhgUwM4wBQEMBcWATnBAOYCUA3sAJBRJbK4QbIC8yA2gOQAMAFh4AafgEYeAXQB0pKABswAE0x4KdBqwTy00%20QjJ5W6gL7BQkWIhTosAIzyEYJctQ2MYzVh25RcMaTIiNDQIYWQ-AIBPNHl9AHcZOUUVDDV3LR09AyMMU3NNJkj2GloAIhi4hHiy-GQyvjEy4Toy4KVahoAmZtagkIha%20sEy4BNmNkKYIA)

Comment: It isn't the same because `["04", "01"]` is inferred as `string[]`.

Comment: But what is wrong in testing if a string is included in a fixed type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See definition of `Array.includes`

```ts
interface Array<T> {
  /**
   * Determines whether an array includes a certain element, 
   * returning true or false as appropriate.
   * @param searchElement The element to search for.
   * @param fromIndex The position in this array at which 
   *   to begin searching for searchElement.
   */
  includes(searchElement: T, fromIndex?: number): boolean;
}
```

`searchElement` needs to be of the same type as the array itself.

This behaviour is not ideal, we would like to say that searchElement belongs to a superset of T - search element can be T or any of its parent types.

There is open proposal [Enable type parameter lower-bound syntax #14520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520) which would enable to implement the desired behaviour of Array.includes in a clean manner.

The `Array.includes` issue re-appears in TS issues, for example

- [Array.prototype.includes fails type-checking when used with Enum subsets #51881](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51881)
- [Array Includes incorrectly uses generic type #53275](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53275)

In your specific case, I would use explicit type `string[]` which allows you to search for any `string`:

```ts
function testb(a:string){
    const colorCodes: string[] = [cat.green, cat.yellow];
    const ans = colorCodes.includes(a);
    console.log(ans)
}
```

See also [TypeScript: Array.includes on narrow types](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-array-includes/)